# How would I find the characteristic equation of this Recurrence Relation?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, recursion, characteristic-functions

Find and solve a recurrence relation for the number of $n$-digit ternary sequences with no consecutive digits being equal.

Since for ternary, meaning only $3$ possible entries for each space, e.g. $0$, $1$, $2$, the first slot $n$ has $3$ possible choices and then each position before ($n-1$, $n-2$, $\ldots$ , $2$, $1$) have $2$ choices each, I got the following recurrence relation:$$a_n=2\cdot a_{n-1}$$

Now I am trying to solve the homogeneous linear recurrence model, but I am stuck in finding a characteristic equation. How would I do this?

Comment: Jared showed you how to find an explicit formula for $a_n$.  Andre provided you with the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients) for a homogeneous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients of order 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual way...just assume that $a_n = A\cdot r^n$ therefore you have:

$$
a_n = 2a_{n-1} \rightarrow Ar^n = 2A\cdot r^{n - 1} = \frac{2A\cdot r^n}{r}\\
1 = \frac{2}{r} \\
r = 2
$$

So $a_n = A\cdot2^n$ (which makes perfect sense since that recursion relation is clearly a simple exponential with common ratio of $2$).

Comment: if $n=1$ then there're $3$ possibilities, if $n=2$ there're $12$. But according to the recurrence relation it should be $a_2=2\cdot a_1=4$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Yos, $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 6$ and $a_3 = 12$. I'm not sure how you got that for $n = 2$ it should be twelve: 1) $01$, 2) $02$, 3) $10$, 4) $12$, 5) $20$, 6) $21$.

Answer (score 2):

Doubling every time should not require a characteristic equation! However, it is $x-2=0$.